# Getting US Highway exit geocodes using Google Maps API?

Tags: geocoding, google-maps-api, software-recommendations

For our application, we need to get all the US interstate highway exits along with their Geocodes. Can you please explain how to get these using Google Maps API or Google Local search or otherwise? So far I have no clue as to how to proceed.

I am looking for a free or a paid solution that is around $1000. I know there are people who provide geocodes. But they are out of our budget.

Several people are suggesting TIGER data with ArcGIS. I know nothing of them.

Comment: Note that using the Google geocoding API for bulk geocoding like this, and storing the data, may be a violation of the terms of service. In addition to the technical restriction (5000 geocodes a day), and social restriction on maps (can only be used on Google Maps, nothing else), I think there's also an additional social restriction that limits how long you can store geocodes for that you should probably look at.

Answer (score 7):

Try Tiger 2010 - your need to select Highway ramps and use the starting node to create a point.
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html
straight forward process.

(in ArcGIS you can do 'vertices to point' and select ID=1)

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I am novice in this area. I only have some GIS knowledge. I tried to read FAQ to understand but that faq did not help much. Can you please explain how to do this. I appreciate you help.

Comment: Additional info to Mapperz' answer: 1) only some states have had their 2010 files released yet, if they haven't, you'd want to try the 2009 files or another source. 2) if you only want interstate exits, you'd have to select from the Tiger Lines file all the ramps (MTFCC code S1630) that intersect with interstates (MTFCC code S1100), then extract a point from the selected lines (like Mapperz says, probably one of the endpoints).  Without ArcGIS, there's other free software to help you do this, for example a program like Quantum GIS (QGIS), or a spatially enabled database like PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Comment: TIGER is a poor choice for this kind of work.

Comment: only if in rural areas - urban coverage is okay. OpenStreetMap integrated the TIGER 2009 Data - it's okay for free

Comment: No, TIGER has no intersection data.  You can't tell for sure if it's an exit or just overlapping lines, not all ramps are mapped, there is no exit information and the MTFCC codes are frequently wrong. I have fairly intimate knowledge of the data.  For this purpose, it is unsuitable.  TIGER road data is not maintained for transportation purposes but only for boundaries of Census geography and to assist in field work. OpenStreetmap adds more information and would be better for free.

Comment: But you can create intersections with GIS tools - have used TIGER data to create Road maps for US mapmakers and worked out the overpasses and underpasses including Ramp Exits and Exit numbers - it was not easy but possible - editorial checks were done and passed to print.

Comment: Well, good on ya then.  I can't imagine trying it but if it worked for you, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You may have to go state by state for this.  Some [states maintain databases of exits](http://www.mass.gov/mgis/exits_rtes.htm) as they are the ones who actually maintain the roads.  You might be able to glean the information from the [Bureau of Transportation Statistics National Transportation Atlas Database](http://www.bts.gov/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/).  That data has some information on intersections.

Also, [OpenStreetmap has some exit data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3ahighway%3Dmotorway_junction), though I don't know how complete it is for the US.

The easiest way is to just buy [ESRI Streetmap data](http://www.esri.com/data/streetmap/index.html).

Comment: I looked at this ESRI streetmap link. They do not quote the price for it. you have any idea how much it could cost in USD?

Comment: I don't know.  I've never been involved in the acquisition. Just ask ESRI for a quote.