# Getting geocodes of US highway EXITS using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

I am developing an application on **Laravel** where I would show nearby hotels around the user's current location. I have successfully done that part. Now if the user is going on the highway, I need to find the next EXIT point of that highway and getting the coordinates of that EXIT point, I have to show nearby hotels around that coordinates. How can I get geocodes for the EXIT points of highway ?

I did some research on HERE.com and ArcGIS for the API's but I am not getting exactly what I am searching.

Comment: Related (but closed) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/getting-us-highway-exit-geocodes-using-google-maps-api

Comment: Yep, I tried the suggestions given in that question but it didn't work for me, so I thought of asking by myself.

Comment: Google Map Directions has the ramp information available example 'ramp-left' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941812/google-directions-api

Comment: can you show your examples - even if they are incorrect?

Comment: sorry, I haven't implemented anything (for this part of application) as I didn't get any reference or code to work on. I read the documentation part in the sites they suggested, but that was not enough for my task.